# Repeated drawings of bounding box

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to simply make a bounding box that uses points(any amount) to follow my mouse around.

Error being when I draw the bounding box currently it repeats all the previous drawings and have repeated bounding boxes
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

width=60
height=80

    
class BoundingBoxWidget(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.original_image = cv2.imread('parking_lot.png')
        self.clone = self.original_image.copy()
        cv2.namedWindow('image')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('image', self.extract_coordinates)

        # Bounding box reference points
        self.image_coordinates = []

    def extract_coordinates(self, event, x, y, flags, parameters):
        self.image_coordinates=[[x,y],[x+width,y],[x+(2*width),y+height],[(x+width),y+height]]
        print(self.image_coordinates)
        points = np.array(self.image_coordinates)
        #points = points.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(self.clone,[points] ,True,(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("image", self.clone) 
    def show_image(self):
        return self.clone

def main():
    boundingbox_widget = BoundingBoxWidget()

    while True:
        cv2.imshow('image', boundingbox_widget.show_image())
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

        # Close program with keyboard 'q'
        if key == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had already the right idea creating a clone from the original image, but just forgot to set the clone back to the original image before painting the new bounding-box upon it. Adding one line at the position as below solves the problem:

```
        self.clone = self.original_image.copy()
        cv2.polylines(self.clone,[points] ,True,(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow("image", self.clone)
```

The code you have provided has along with the issue described in your question and solved by above described change also some other issues you haven't addressed in your question. The most annoying one is that it unnecessary heats up the CPU because it updates the screen in both, the keyboard and the mouse events loops with highest possible rate for mouse events and a very high rate for keyboard events. This causes heating up the CPU even in case the mouse stands still.

The code provided below does not heat up the CPU. It uses the `time` module for own time queries and sets the frame rate to 25 frames per second for mouse events. The keyboard input loop runs at a rate of 4 queries per second and raises the window again if closed by Alt-F4 or clicking [x]. The only way to quit the program is therefore pressing [q] on the keyboard (this is the same behavior as in the code you have posted).

To make things simpler the code below flattens the depth of function calls by getting rid of the class handling the bounding box widget using global variables in the mouse handler function, the only function in the code. See comments, changed variable names (in order to better mirror their actual purpose) and the way function parameter are set in the code for further explanations.

Comprehend the behavior of both the mouse and keyboard loops checking out what the code prints to stdout:

```
import cv2                    as cv
import numpy                  as np
from time import perf_counter as T

BB_BASE_WIDTH = 60
BB_HEIGHT     = 80
BB_SKEW_CORR  = 20
FRAMERATE     = 25.0

image = cv.imread('parking_lot.jpg')
clone = image.copy()
cv.namedWindow('image')
last_update_time = T()

def mouseCallbackHandler(event, x, y, flags, parameters):
    # mouse events query loop
    global BB_BASE_WIDTH, BB_HEIGHT, FRAMERATE
    global image, clone, last_update_time
    if T() - last_update_time > 1.0 / FRAMERATE: 
        bb_poly = [
            (x                             , y),
            (x+BB_BASE_WIDTH               , y),
            (x+2*BB_BASE_WIDTH+BB_SKEW_CORR, y+BB_HEIGHT),
            (x+BB_BASE_WIDTH+BB_SKEW_CORR  , y+BB_HEIGHT), 
        ]
        print(bb_poly)
        points = np.array(bb_poly)
        clone = image.copy()
        cv.polylines(
            clone, [points], True, (255,0,0), 2, cv.LINE_AA
        ) # [ cv.FILLED, cv.LINE_4, cv.LINE_8, cv.LINE_AA ]
        # LINE_4: 4-connected, LINE_8: 8-connected, LINE_AA: antialiased         
        cv.imshow('image', clone)
        last_update_time = T()
    # cv.imshow("image", clone) # show at mouse events framerate 
#:def mouseCallbackHandler()
cv.setMouseCallback('image', mouseCallbackHandler)

def main():
    while True: # keyboard input query loop
        cv.imshow('image', clone) # show if closed by Alt-F4 or [x]
        print('while True')
        last_update_time = T()
        key = cv.waitKey(250) # keyboard input query rate
        # Close program with keyboard 'q'
        if key == ord('q'):
            print('exit(1)')
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ah that worked was wondering where the small error was.

Comment: See my updated answer for an updated bounding-box which better mirrors the parking slot skew.

Comment: The skew for the parking lot will be changed later so it's pointless currently.

Comment: I am still not able to slow down the loop ... waitKey delay value has no effect on  frame-rate as the frame rate is probably controlled by the frame rate of mouse events not the while loop. Hmmm ... and ... yes ... pointless but ... I had fun with it playing around with the code.

Comment: Check out the code in updated answer. Next to some other issues it fixes the issue with unnecessary heating up the CPU.

Comment: move the imshow out of the loop. you need that only once to start the window and populate it with something. any updates are coming from the imshow in the callback. -- the right structure would be to have some kind of `draw()` method, that is called once before the loop, and every time the event handler has something new to show the `waitKey()` should not have any time at all, just 0, for infinite wait. there is no need to spin there at all. "frame rate", here, has no business even being a thing. remove all that stuff. it does nothing.

Comment: and please remove those `:=`, that's the "walrus operator"... so you're accidentally _defining_ (or overwriting!) those variables in that scope. terribly wrong. please... stop. just stick to the core of the question, which was that OP kept drawing into the same array, instead of clearing it with a fresh copy of the background image.

Comment: oh, I just noticed, due to your use of the walrus operator here, you _aren't_ actually using named arguments, even though it looks like you do. this is **deceptive**. that call, as you write it (`cv.polylines(img:=clone, pts:=[points], isClosed:=True, color:=(255,0,0), thickness:=2, lineType:=cv.LINE_AA)`), requires the *order* of arguments to be right. there is absolutely no reason to use the walrus operator here, other than to mislead beginners.

Comment: Removing the imshow out of the loop is not a good idea as if the window will be closed by Alt-F4 it won't be raised again but the script will keep running in the background without giving a chance to quit it as the window is not more there. Have you a link to a script having such loops in the right structures allowing setting a frame-rate alone with the waitKey() I can learn from how to do it right?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing the issue with the walrus operator out. By the way: how can I get all the texts of my questions and answers along with the links to them here on stackoverflow? Or at least a list with links to all my answers/questions?